# API Gateway Request map format for json with single quotes

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway, velocity

I'm working in cdk and producing an api gateway resource. I need to supply a request template that looks like this:

```
$util.escapeJavaScript(data).replaceAll("\\'","'")
```

but I can't figure out how to format this in the typescript cdk code:. Here's the error code when you just blindly type it in without making any effort:

```
lib/factory/api-gateway/api-gw-factory.ts:119:68 - error TS1127: Invalid character.

119       bodyjson : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")",
    
lib/factory/api-gateway/api-gw-factory.ts:119:74 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

119       bodyjson : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")",
```

doesn't work obviously. I've tried a heap of other things. I've found that the formatting I need to get the code to compile just gets fed straight into the output template.

I.e. the following compiles, but the escape characters end up in the generated output...

```
bodyjson : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll(\"\\'\",\"'\")",
```

leads to :

```
{
    "bodyjson": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll(\"\\'\",\"'\")",
```

in the template... Which is clearly not sensible apache velocity.

I even tried this:

```
const testStr = "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')).replaceAll(\"\\'\",\"'\")";
const escapedStr = testStr.replace(/\"/g,'"');

let requestTemplate: {[index: string]:any} = {
  "bodyjson" : escapedStr, // escapes reappear in template!
```

but the escape characters reappear in the cursed template afterwards!

How do I achieve the desired output format?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to use [`String.raw()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

Like

```js
String.raw`$util.escapeJavaScript(data).replaceAll("\\'","'")`
```

Comment: Oh crumbs. I marked this as correct, but found that I'd accidentally tested different code. Afraid this still results in .replaceAll(\"\\'\",\"'\") in the template somehow. Which is so frustrating, since this really should work!

Comment: That is weird. If I use `String.raw` in my projects the string remains as is

Comment: I've double checked and what I get is this : .replaceAll(\"\\\\'\",\"'\")",    There must be something messed up with my code or package versions... Looks like an extra JSON.stringify is hiding somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The sticking point was that the requestTemplate has to be converted to a string in the LambdaOptions object. So, some extra manipulation is required first. Here's the full solution:

```
private _initDefLambdaOptions(options: any) {

  let requestTemplate: {[index: string]:any} = {
    "bodyjson" : String.raw`$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')).replaceAll("\\'","'")`
  };

  let requestTemplateString = JSON.stringify(requestTemplate, null, 4);
  requestTemplateString     = requestTemplateString.replaceAll("\\\"", "\""); // remove \" escapes
  requestTemplateString     = requestTemplateString.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"); // remove \\ escapes


  this._defLambdaOptions  = {
    // Integration Request Quadrant:
    // ----------------------------
      proxy: false,
      requestParameters: {
        // 'integration.request.querystring.unused': 'method.request.querystring.unused'
      },
      allowTestInvoke: true,
      passthroughBehavior: apiGateway.PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES,
      requestTemplates: {
        // 'application/json': JSON.stringify(requestTemplate, null, 4)   // This is breaking the repaceAll("\\'","'") by escaping everything!
        'application/json': requestTemplateString                         // Solves repaceAll("\\'","'")
      },
...
```

Then this LambdaOptions object is used to create in the apiGateway.LambdaIntegration API.

```
public addMethod(resource: apiGateway.Resource, method: string, lambda: lambda.IFunction, options?: any) {
  this._customiseOptions(lambda.functionName, options);
  this._lambdaOptions = this._initDefLambdaOptions(options);
  const lambdaInt  = new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(lambda, this._lambdaOptions);
  resource.addMethod(method, lambdaInt, this._methodOptions);
```